# How to remove Neighborhood and Address 2 fields in commerce kickstart?

Tags: 7, commerce

In shipping information form there is these 2 fields( Neighborhood and Address 2 ) which I need to remove but I can not find the solution. Any help?

Comment: I added `7` as tag. For future questions, please remember to add the Drupal version # as tag, thx.

Answer (score 1):

If you log in as admin:

1. Got to: admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types
2. Select the "manage fields" for the correct profile
3. Edit the Address field
4. Under "Format handlers" there should be checkboxes to hide the fields you do not want to show.

To do via code, see [Use only one address field](https://www.drupal.org/node/1337656#comment-9422167)

Comment: This hides both fields of the address field. I want to hide only Address2 field.

Comment: That's where you hide fields, unless you do it via code. To do via code, see: https://www.drupal.org/node/1337656#comment-9422167